Stop Kubernetes from redeploying a pod from deployment
I'm trying to manually control a pods lifespan, but I can't seem to control that the pod should not restart, after being terminated manually.
The concepts is this:

Apply deployment file
Make changes to the codebase being used in the deployment
Apply the deployment file again
Both pods should now be running
I will manually terminate the oldest pod when I want to
Only the newest pod should be running

The deployment file is like this
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: my-service-deployment
  labels:
    app: my-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-service
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-service
        image: my-service:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 81

Any idea how to accomplish this? I have tried scaling up/down the replicas via the api, but without any luck
I have tried to use restartPolicy like this:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: my-service-deployment
  labels:
    app: my-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-service
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-service
        image: my-service:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 81
      restartPolicy: Never

And that results in this error
The Deployment "my-service" is invalid: spec.template.spec.restartPolicy: Unsupported value: "Never": supported values: "Always"


Set a restartPolicy, the default one is Always, which means Pods will keep restarting no matter what exit status.

@deHaar I have tried to set a restartPolicy to never but it will only accept always

OK, you're right, unfortunately… Deployments only accept Always, see this answer to a similar question.

Maybe a single Pod may accept other values than Always… That would mean you cannot use a Deployment for your use case.

If you update the deployment the old pods will be replaced by the new ones without you doing any manual intervention

And if you want to run bare pod on your cluster (without a controler), just do not use a deployment

@Will but I don't want the pod to automatically do a rolling update, I have other services dependent on the output of my-service and the output of the my-service is dependant on previous output values, so I would like to wait for the output to be as expected, before terminating the oldest pod

Adding from Will's comment, instead of using a deployment you can consider using a StatefulSet instead. From the docs,

StatefulSet is the workload API object used to manage stateful applications.
Manages the deployment and scaling of a set of Pods, and provides guarantees about the ordering and uniqueness of these Pods.
Like a Deployment, a StatefulSet manages Pods that are based on an identical container spec. Unlike a Deployment, a StatefulSet maintains a sticky identity for each of its Pods. These pods are created from the same spec, but are not interchangeable: each has a persistent identifier that it maintains across any rescheduling.

Note that when you delete a pod kubectl delete pod <pod_name>, the StatefulSet will still replace the pod, you may run the command kubectl scale statefulset my-service-statefulset --replicas=0 to scale it down to 0.

I have tried to look into StatefulSet, but can I still be able to apply the deployment file again (with a pod already running with the old deployment file) and use scaling to have both of the pods running, and when their output is as expected, scale it down again to terminate the oldest pod?
